# Sending a JSON object with cURL to a specific url

Tags: php, json, api, curl

I'm not quite understanding how to format my cURL call to the Mandrill API...

```
$specific_api = "/messages/send.json";
$url = "https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/" . specific_api . "?";

$param_array = array(
                    'key' => $apikey,
                    'template_name' => 'mytemplate',
                    'template_content' => array(
                            'name' => 'main',
                            'content' => 'This is HAPPENING RIGHT NOW!'
                        ),
                    'message' => array(
                        'subject' => 'blanketID Service: Pet Found',
                        'from_email' => 'no-reply@blanketid.com',
                        'from_name' => 'blanketID Service',
                        'to' => array(
                            'email' => 'devinmightbe@gmail.com',
                            'name' => 'Devin Columbus'
                        )
                    )
                );

$encoded = json_encode($param_array);

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $encoded);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$arr = json_decode($data, true);

echo $data;
```

I'm really not even sure that I've got this all setup correctly ...

Comment: I'm thinking that there's no point to the `"?"` portion..

Comment: Yes, you can leave the '?' out of the URL. You are using a POST request not GET.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not confident, but having the read the documentation at php.net with regards to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, I believe the format you are passing is not accepted.

```
The full data to post in a HTTP "POST" operation. To post a file, prepend a filename with @ and use the full path. The filetype can be explicitly specified by following the filename with the type in the format ';type=mimetype'. This parameter can either be passed as a urlencoded string like 'para1=val1&para2=val2&...' or as an array with the field name as key and field data as value. If value is an array, the Content-Type header will be set to multipart/form-data. As of PHP 5.2.0, value must be an array if files are passed to this option with the @ prefix.
```